# Is it misconduct to change a wrong answer to a copy of another answer?

Tags: discussion, users, comment-flags

I quickly answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30879338/how-can-i-make-this-function-watch-for-changes) with a quick hack that admittedly is not the best solution, which I completely agreed with @jfriend00 about, and upvoted his answer as well. However, the user @Nassim posted a blatantly wrong answer later which I downvoted and requested him to remove. He deleted it, then updated it to an almost exact copy of my answer which he then undeleted. He has now posted on my answer:

> this code does not run , please delete

which is incorrect, and has posted on his answer:

> i did update my code please remove the down vote

I've already flagged his comment on my post, and flagged his answer for the specific reason I just stated above. Is there anything else I can do, and am I correct in having flagged him for this?

**EDIT**

I've come to the embarrassing realization that my original answer was indeed incorrect, and that the other user's answer was not plagarism as I previously thought. My intention was not to "distribute pitchforks on Meta" but I was concerned about the user's reaction which I still believe was on some level a petty revenge. I apologize for overlooking the mistake in my answer and I apologize to @Nassim for having wrongly accused him of plagarism.

Comment: If its a *copy* then he plagarized, and you can flag for that

Comment: The only thing he changed was ``if($('#b:contains("0 items")'))`` to ``if($('#b').text() == "0 items")``, which does the exact same thing.

Comment: Asking to delete the post is very strange from my point of view. I've never seen such comment and would never make one myself.

Comment: That odd comment he posted seems to indicate some form of revenge if you ask me. It looks like it has all been cleaned up now.

Comment: This is the basic reason why you don't have to leave a comment when you DV a poor post.  Entirely too much drama.  Just vote, nothing else.  If you leave a comment to help the user improve his post then just don't vote until later, after he's had a chance to follow-up on it.  Drama avoided.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts *"which does the exact same thing"* is false. The first is a jQuery object which will always loosely convert to `true`. The other one is dependent on if `#b` exists and what it's text is.

Comment: Definitely not a case of plagiarism. while the answers are similar, they certainly aren't the same.

Comment: @Sam so the "copied" answer really is an improvement because Patrick's code didn't work...

Comment: In the future, maybe wait to see how your flags are handled before distributing pitchforks on Meta.

Comment: You can comment if you downvote a post, (and I would, even at the risk of revenge downvotes), but such a comment should explain what's wrong or suggest an improvement rather than requesting deletion.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Instead of telling people what you want them to do, simply stick to the facts and point out *why* something is wrong/bad/sub-par and leave your vote. It's hard to argue with facts, and it might even bring some enlightenment. Leave it up to the poster to fix their answer or delete it. Stack Overflow is all about technical accuracy and precision, not about interpersonal drama and "being right" or such. Don't unnecessarily create drama by "attacking" a person, stick to productively critiquing their work.

If the user fixes their code based on your comment, then repeat the above (critique the new version of the code). If it ends up being 100% plagiarism, you might want to flag for that. However, if there's even some difference in the code, again: evaluate what the difference really is and critique based on that. Maybe it fixes an important bug that you overlooked.

We're all just trying to come to workable solutions to problems here. Bring your best intentions to the game. Leave ego at home.